# How to disable the "Please Install the Windows Live Device manager" dialog?

Tags: usb, windows-live-messenger

Whenever I plug in a USB device, Windows Live Messenger pops up the dialog box:

> Please Install the Windows Live Device manager

How can I disable it other than by actually installing the software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the related pages on Google, the only solution that seems to work is:

- Install it,
- Run `msconfig` (start > run > msconfig) and disable it from the Startup tab.

Comment: Windows Live Messenger?

Comment: The bet is to install Windows Live Device manager, and then disable it from msconfig's startup tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it without installing the software by editing the registry:

- Start / Run / regedit
- Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\
- Create Key: MSNDeviceManager
- Add string: InstallDir
- Add value for the string to be: %windir%

When exported the key should look like:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSNDeviceManager]
"InstallDir"="%windir%"
```

This worked for me (winXp).